# Why does PEVerify say the CLR is expecting a single dimension array for statically sized arrays?

Tags: .net, clr, cil

This code fails verification:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}
.assembly Program {}

.method private static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 3

    .locals init ( int32[0 ... 10] a )

    ldc.i4 10
    newarr int32
    stloc.0

    ldloc.0
    ldc.i4.0
    ldc.i4.s 32
    stelem.i4

    call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
    pop
    ret
}
```

With the following error:

> [IL]: Error: [C:[...]Program.exe : ::Main ][offset 0x0000000F] Expected single dimension array. 1 Error(s) Verifying Program.exe

Yet this code verifies fine:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}
.assembly Program {}

.method private static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 3

    .locals init ( int32[] a )

    ldc.i4 10
    newarr int32
    stloc.0

    ldloc.0
    ldc.i4.0
    ldc.i4.s 32
    stelem.i4

    call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
    pop
    ret
}
```

Is this an unimplemented feature, an error in the CLR or PEVerify, or simply a misunderstanding of usage? The programs both execute fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess -- and it's only a guess -- is that this is related to the distinction between vectors and arrays.

The [ECMA CLI Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (Partition II, Sections 14.1 and 14.2) says this:

> Vectors are single-dimension arrays with a zero lower bound.  They
>   have direct support in CIL instructions (`newarr`, `ldelem`, `stelem`,
>   and `ldelema`).
>
> [...]
>
> While vectors have direct support through CIL instructions, all other
>   arrays are supported by the VES by creating subtypes of the abstract
>   class `System.Array`.

Vectors are declared using `T[]` syntax, whereas arrays can be declared in various ways using `T[n]`, `T[p,q]`, `T[x...y]` etc. So, in your first example, the `int32[0 ... 10]` syntax is an *array* declaration. In your second example, the `int32[]` syntax is a *vector* declaration.

My guess is that the verifier objects to your first example because it thinks that you're trying to use `newarr` and `stelem` on an *array* rather than a *vector*. Presumably the verifier is only examining the type of declaration and doesn't take the rank, bounds etc of the array into account. The reason both examples execute properly is because a 1-dimension array with a zero lower-bound *is* a vector, to all intents and purposes.

As for why the error message says "Expected single dimension array" rather than "Expected vector", I have no idea!

Comment: So would that mean the proper way to index an `array` as in my first example is by accessing through its indexer?

Comment: @Michael: I suppose so. Another option would be to use the [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getvalue.aspx), [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.setvalue.aspx) etc methods. And you'd construct it using `newobj` rather than `newarr`. (The CLI spec also says that the runtime provides specialised constructors and `Get` and `Set` methods that aren't present in the `Array` type's metadata.)